# Is explicit variable declaration in case of subsequent function calls necessary in Scala?

Tags: scala

Quoting 'Programming in Scala':

```
//Code snippet 1:
def grep(pattern: String) =
  for (
    file <- filesHere
    if file.getName.endsWith(".scala");
    line <- fileLines(file)
    if line.trim.matches(pattern)
  ) println(file +": "+ line.trim)

//Code snippet 2    
def grep(pattern: String) =
  for {
    file <- filesHere
    if file.getName.endsWith(".scala")
    line <- fileLines(file)
    trimmed = line.trim /*********Question is about this line*********/
    if trimmed.matches(pattern)
  } println(file +": "+ trimmed)
```

Motivation of introduction of `trimmed` is as follows:

> Note that the previous code repeats the expression line.trim. This is a
>   non-trivial computation, so you might want to only compute it once.

I've seen some statements in situations like this that such variables are redundant because compiler will take care about repetitive function calls by means of caching or introducing such a variable by itself so user shouldn't bother about that. Is that correct or I should always introduce such a variable myself? (And does Java differ from Scala in this? 'cause I've seen that statements concerning Java, not Scala).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not cache the computation automatically. How should it? Since Scala doesn't have an effect system, the compiler doesn't know if the function being executed has side effects or not. Thus, not repeating a computation due to potential performance improvements could lead to different behavior:

```
scala> for (i <- Option(5) if {println(i); i*i} < 50) yield {println(i); i*i}
5
5
res0: Option[Int] = Some(25)

scala> for (i <- Option(5); j = {println(i); i*i} if j < 50) yield j
5
res1: Option[Int] = Some(25)
```

Btw, you can always check what code the compiler generates:

```
$ scala -Xprint:typer -e "for (i <- Option(5) if {println(i); i*i} < 50) yield {println(i); i*i}"
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // scalacmd5404327798073027065.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val args: Array[String] = argv;
      {
        final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
          def <init>(): anonymous class $anon = {
            $anon.super.<init>();
            ()
          };
          scala.Option.apply[Int](5).withFilter(((i: Int) => {
            scala.this.Predef.println(i);
            i.*(i)
          }.<(50))).map[Int](((i: Int) => {
            scala.this.Predef.println(i);
            i.*(i)
          }))
        };
        {
          new $anon();
          ()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

5
5
```

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty comprehensive answer. I'm a Scala newbie, but I got it nice and clearly.